# Are there any natural anti-lice for cats?

Tags: cats, medicines, parasites

I use `Advantage` drops from BAYER  on my outdoor cat and it is effective for about a month.

However I feel bad each time that I apply it, because the cat becomes drowsy for a day or two and I fear that we also get contaminated by some nasty chemicals when we caress the cat.

On the other hand, if I don't use the drop, the cat get infested regularly by lice in summer time.

So I'm wondering if there are some effective but natural alternatives available, which are harmless for cats and  humans?

Comment: Advantage is already harmless to cats and people. I doubt you'll find anything safer that's still effective. I've never noticed my cats being drowsy from it, although they do sometimes sulk for a day or two because they don't like having it applied to them. Maybe that's what you're seeing?.

Comment: What's your reference to the claim that Advantage is `harmless to cats and people`? I hope it's not Bayer's PR ads.

Comment: Veterinarians. What's your reference that it's harmful?

Comment: You could ask your vet if you can swap to Merial's broadline. Like advantage/advocate, it is applied monthly behind the shoulder blades. It comes in a pre-loaded syringe, rather than a single-use tube.